# Posting results from remote DB lookup in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a small 'distributed' system based on 2 servers . app A is written in python and I would like it to access a controller in my base program B (written in codeigniter). I have written the following controller 'data_controller' in B containing:

```
function index()
{

       $t = R::findOne('times');
       $postArray = $t->export();

}
```

I'm using the redbeanphp ORM. The code above picks a single record from the db and turns the row into an key-value array. I want to http Post this to App A by letting A open:

```
http:localhost/appB/index.php/data_controller
```

what do I need to do next to send the content of $postArray to App A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [output the data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and have Python [decode the data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). You can output the data as JSON from CodeIgniter like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;');
echo json_encode($postArray);
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. For my own info how does doing it this way compare to http posting, security wise

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "http posting, security wise". Anyone who can access the URL of the CodeIgniter controller will be able to view the data. Is that what you're referencing?

Comment: sorry vvanasten , I'm not very knowledgeable about security matters and this is not a major concern in this case anyway.  I have read that http POST is usually considered more secure than GET. I wondered how outputting the data using JSON would compare. - Bill

Comment: In this case POST vs GET doesn't really apply since you want Application B to output the data when Application A requests it, and would only be a concern if you reversed that process (Application B pushes the data to Application B, either via POST or GET). If you're concerned about security you should probably look into doing this over SSL and using an authentication mechanism (like having API keys), but that's outside of the scope of this answer.